# add string at beginning of each array entry

Tags: arrays, foreach, zsh

For example, I have `a=(1 2 3)` and I want to get `a=(foo1 foo2 foo3)`. What would be an easy/clean way to get that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a=(foo$^a[@])`